# Using Constexpr specifier in a derived class's function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, constexpr

Forgive me if this is an ignorant question, but i am still wrapping my head around when and how to use the `constexpr` specifier. (compiling with msvc 14). 
I am working on a simple base class that allows you to wrap an arbitrary object into a "constexpr object." It looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class basic_const {
public:

    explicit constexpr basic_const(const T& value) : data_(value) {  }

    template <typename...Args>
    constexpr basic_const(Args&&...args) : data_(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) { }

    virtual ~basic_const() = default;

    constexpr const T& data() const noexcept { return data_; }

private:
    T data_;
};
```

Everything works as expected, i can successfully create an object of any type that can (obviously) qualify as `constexpr`.

Here is the problem:
When trying to inherit from this class, i cannot implement additional `constexpr` member functions, but i can ctors. The following code is for a `constexpr` string class i am implementing:

```
class str_const : public basic_const<const char*>
{
public:

    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr str_const(const char(&str)[N]) :
         basic_const(str), sz_(N) {}
    ...
    constexpr std::size_t size() const noexcept{ return sz_; } // error here
    ...
public:
    std::size_t sz_;
};
```

*Can i create constexpr member functions in a derived class?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems not to be what you wrote in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36535834/3093378). The problem is that the enclosing class is not a [literal type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType), due to the existence of a virtual destructor (i.e., a [non-trivial destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Trivial_destructor)). gcc spits out (emphasize mine):

> error: **enclosing class** of constexpr non-static member function 'std::size_t str_const::size() const' **is not a literal type**

[<kbd>Live example with the error</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffc45c34c4aeb3f2)

Remove the `virtual` qualifier from the destructor and it will work.

[<kbd>Live example working</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef52daf7cf2b71b0)

There is no need for additional `const`s for the member variables.

**EDIT**

clang however [compiles your code just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6d143ead35a489d)... wonder if this is a bug. Now realized that this is indeed a clang bug, as a [virtual destructor is non-trivial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Trivial_destructor), so clang shouldn't compile your code as is.

Comment: @NowhereMan You're welcome, good question. I'm still trying to come up with a minimal example for filling a clang bug.

Comment: The restriction that constexpr member functions may only be declared for literal types was a C++11 limitation, retroactively lifted from C++11 with CWG1684 and removed from C++14 altogether. GCC is wrong here, Clang is correct, and thus this answer is wrong. ;-D (EDIT: The specific wording that was changed was in [dcl.constexpr]/8; the sentence "*The class of which that function is a member shall be a literal type.*" was removed.)

Comment: @ildjarn I think you should post an answer rather than a comment. I definitely didn't dig in so deep, so a complete answer may be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what i am trying too accomplish is perfectly acceptable, the member variable in the derived class was not declared `const`, changing the variables in both the base and derived class to `const` fixed the problem.